# JSON raw POST cURL request not working

Tags: php, http, curl, postman, guzzle

any help is very appreciated, thanks in advance.

my storeCallback.php file which i have hosted at: http://xxxxx/storeCallback.php

```
<?php
die(var_dump($_REQUEST));
```

and i am creating a post json raw request as:

1.

```
$url = "http://xxxxx/storeCallback.php/storeCallback.php";

$body =['foo' => 'bar'];

$body_string = json_encode($body);

$header = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body_string),
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_string);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
die(var_dump($response));
```

2.

```
$url = "http://xxxxx/storeCallback.php/storeCallback.php";

$body =['foo' => 'bar'];

$body_string = json_encode($body);

$header = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body_string),
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_string);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
die(var_dump($response));
```

3.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('http://xxxxx/storeCallback.php/storeCallback.php', [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['for' => "bar"],
]);

echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

**Nothing is working, in all cases response is [] (empty array)**
but sending request like http://xxxxx/storeCallback.php/storeCallback.php?foo=bar is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code, first of all the `storeCallback.php` file does not provide valid JSON output, therefore you cannot parse it as JSON when you try to retrieve it using cURL.

The proper version is the following:
**storeCallback.php**

```
<?php
die(json_encode($_REQUEST));
?>
```

Furthermore, you should be making the cURL request as follows:

```
<?php
$url = "http://pc.medimetry.in/storeCallback.php";
$body = ['foo' => 'bar'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); //important, always close cURL connections.
$parsed_response = json_decode($json_response);
var_dump($parsed_response);
?>
```

);